# How can I set min max init date?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to set min, max and init date to my uib datepicker?
What I have done doesn't work. I don't know where I am wrong.

HTML:

```
<input id="field_datePremierJour" type="text" class="form-control" name="datePremierJour" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}"
       ng-model="vm.conge.datePremierJour" is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.datePremierJour"
       datepicker-options="vm.optionsDate"

/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar('datePremierJour')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

JS:

```
vm.optionsDate = {
   minDate:new Date(2017,0,10),
   maxDate:new Date(2017,0,30),
   initDate:new Date(2017,0,10)
}
```

Comment: Issue with the date range ? or date picker itself is not opening ?

Comment: Can you show more of your angular controller?  Such as how "vm" is declared.

Comment: Define "doesn't work", precisely. What are you doing, whet do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Even if minDate is set to 2017-01-10, I can pick a date previous to minDate. Same for maxDate. And cursor doesn't point on initDate.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you either have to provide a valid Date object to `ng-model` or have an `initDate`

[Datepicker popup](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup)

> initDate  (Default: null) - The initial date view when no model value is specified.

Either remove `initDate` and provide a valid date to ngModel or remove the ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution

```
<input id="field_datePremierJour" type="text" class="form-control" name="datePremierJour" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}"
       ng-model="vm.conge.datePremierJour" is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.datePremierJour"
       min-date:"vm.minDate" max-date:"vm.maxDate"
/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar('datePremierJour')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```